# How to install WordPress in subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, subdomain

At the moment I have a WordPress installation in a subfolder of my current site (`example.com/wordpress`). How do I make it so that wordpress is accessible from a subdomain?

I.e. I would like wordpress to be accessible from this address: `wordpress.example.com`, and that all the links, posts and pages will still work flawlessly, e.g. `wordpress.example.com/my-wp-post/`

If it makes a difference which host one is with, I am asking specifically about 1&1.

Thank you

Comment: You create a sub-domain and upload wordpress to it. Technically www is a subdomain, so out of the box you should have no problems.

Answer (score 16):

I am not a big fan of video tutorials, but I used [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kYEf8pfg4Q) to successfully set up a new subdomain and install wordpress.

Here is an overview of the process

1. Use cpanel to create the subdomain
2. Download the latest version of wordpress to your local drive
3. Upload to subdomain folder on your host
4. Extract the files, and move them into the subdomain folder
5. Use cpanel SQL Wizard to create a new data base
6. Make a note of the username, db name and db password
7. Copy wp-config-sample.php to wp-config.php in the subdomain folder
8. Edit wp-config.php to add the username, db name and db password
9. Open the URL "your-subdomain.your-domain.com/wp-admin/install.php"
10. Fill out the fields on the form and press "install wordpress"

After creating the a subdomain I use [WP clone](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/) to create and install a backup of my live site into the new subdomain.  The clone site allows me to verify updates before deploying them my public site.

Hopefully the OP has resolved this issue, but maybe this will be of use to others.

Comment: how do you prevent the site from automatically forwarding to the root? I keep getting a 404 error saying root.com/subdirectory/wp-admin/(etc) doesn't exist on the root server—I can't access the subdirectory install at all

Comment: @Jan, Hard to say, but I am guessing it is either your "wp-config.php" file or ".htaccess".  Or perhaps it is an issue with the subdirectory permissions.

Comment: This worked for me, except for steps 6 and 8, I would include the db host address.

Comment: You probably want to also replace links to root with links to subdomain in the entire DB, e.g. for links in the comments. I use wp-cli for that (it has a search-replace command) but for me it works only on the local version of the website's DB which I frequently move to the staging site.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 options.

1) Manually:

Copy your wordpress install from the subfolder of your main domain to the subdomain's folder. Using a database editing tool (of your choice) go into the wp_options table and change the option_value of the option_name 'siteurl' and 'home'.

You might have a few other options that will need editing, but they are more often than not plugin specific.

2) A little better:

Create a new wordpress install in your subdomain. Copy your plugins, themes and uploads into it. Then, install the plugin wp-migrate-db-pro from https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/ Use this plugin to copy the database from the subfolder install to the subdomain install. This plugin will globally search and replace the URLs and Folders for you.

I've been using this plugin for a while...and it saves me hours and hours of work.

Answer (score 1):

Purchase your unique URL or subdomain or wherever you want the wordpress to live from your host provider.

```
wordpress.example.com

coolurl.cooltimes.com
```

upload Wordpress to that root. `/`

Or define a custom folder for it;

```
wordpress.example.com/partywp/
```

**NOTE**: If your looking for the free *(no hosting required - though less custom website friendly)* wordpress with similar URL, please use wordpress.com version and you don't need to do anything.

http://wordpress.com/ is different from http://wordpress.org/

Wordpress.com is like google blogger and you simply create an account and they give you a URL - and free blogging area with small templates. You can transfer your free wordpress.com to custom wordpress.org -- if you would like to use wordpress hosting naming convention, consult wordpress.

**Added:**

If you are changing the location from your original install; to a different path or location. You should then uninstall the Wordpress that is elsewhere or previous, and reinstall at where you want it to currently live to avoid any wholes or errors, etc.

So, if now it must be at: `wordpress.example.com` -- work with your host provider (hopefully not godaddy) locate the root to this domain, and reinstall with a fresh latest version and you should be OK. If you have further DNS issues, please try to describe your question more clearly.

Comment: Thank you. I'm talking about a self-hosted wordpress.org site though. All my host allows me to do though is create a subdomain that links to a subfolder - not to create a separate root - so how can I ensure that my wordpress installation in my subfolder still works perfectly even when its URL has been changed (from `example.com/wordpress/` to `wordpress.example.com`)? I tried simply linking my `example.com/wordpress/` to the `wordpress.example.com` folder, but the pages and css wouldn't load properly, due to URL mismatches.

Comment: I don't fully understand what your saying; but, if you are changing the location from your original install; to a different path or location. You should then uninstall the Wordpress that is elsewhere or previous, and reinstall at where you want it to currently live to avoid any wholes or errors, etc.